# Jest: Can only re-mock implementation when running a single test

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following simplified example where I'm manually mocking a dependency and getting it to return a resolved Promise. In one of my tests I then attempt to change its return type to a Promise rejection.

If I run all 3 tests together they fail, because the call in the test for rejection actually resolves. However, if I modify line 17 in the spec to `it.only('should reject if the client fails to load'` then the single test passes.

What am I doing wrong?

**`service.js`:**

```
import client from './client';

const service = (() => {
  let instance;

  const makeCall = () => {
    return true;
  };

  const init = async () => {
    const _client = await client();

    return Promise.resolve({
      makeCall,
    });
  };

  const getInstance = async () => {
    if (!instance) {
      instance = await init();
    }

    return Promise.resolve(instance);
  };

  return {
    getInstance,
  };
})();

export default service;
```

**`client.js`:**

```
const client = () => Promise.resolve('Real');

export default client;
```

**`__test__/service.spec.js`:**

```
import client from '../client';
import service from '../service';

jest.mock('../client');

describe('Service', () => {
  it('should return a singleton', () => {
    expect(service.getInstance()).toEqual(service.getInstance());
  });

  it('should resolve if the client successfully loads', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    await expect(service.getInstance()).resolves.toHaveProperty('makeCall');
  });

  it('should reject if the client fails to load', async () => {
    const errorMessage = 'Client could not be initialised.';

    expect.assertions(1);
    client.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.reject(new Error(errorMessage)));

    await expect(service.getInstance()).rejects.toHaveProperty(
      'message',
      errorMessage
    );
  });
});
```

**`__mocks__/client.js`:**

```
const client = jest.fn();
client.mockImplementation(() => {
  return Promise.resolve('Mock file');
});

export default client;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by trying to mock the dependencies of a Singleton.

When running all three tests, the original mock implementation (that resolves) is used and is then not replaced by the second mock implementation that rejects.

It's also worth noting that because the rejected Promise is created but therefore not handled, this results in an unhandled Promise rejection and the test suite crashes.